# how to move ispell correction suggestion window

Tags: ispell

When running `ispell-buffer`, as I scroll down the document, the misspelled word is highlighted at the bottom of the window, but the correction suggestion window appears at the top of the document. Is there a way to make the correction suggestion window appear at the bottom of the window it is being executed in instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `ispell.el` has evolved over time.  As to Emacs 28.2, see the function `ispell-display-buffer` ....  (You can use `M-x find-function` once the `ispell.el` library has been loaded.)  There a couple of times the parameter `'above` is used when calling `split-window` ... that parameter can be changed to `'below` ... To redefine a function, it can be copied to the `.emacs` / `init.el` file ... make sure the library `ispell.el` has been loaded before redefining a function inside that library.

Comment: Terrific, thanks - I was able to add the modified function to use-package under `:config` and it worked perfectly without having to manually load ispell. Thanks!